# JScript error when clicking button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, jscript

I am getting a JScript when clicking a button but I get this error before the button event or page load event and it doesn't seem to be erroring on any user code.  Here is the error popup:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server.
```

The status code returned from the server was: 500
In debug mode, the following throw is highlighted which is causing the popup:

```
if(d&&!e.get_errorHandled())throw d.
```

I do not know if this helps but if I take out a textbox from a column in a gridview, this stops failing.
  I have several textboxes and it doesn't matter which textbox I remove, as long as it is one of them.  Can anyone point me to the issue?

thanks, bob

Comment: The JavaScript doesn't help us solve the problem. Please remove it and include any relevant code directly to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it has to do with maxing out a collection's index within http processing on the server.  I was loading a grid with about 10 columns and 300 rows.  After debugging the JScript, I eventually got an error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object".  This led me to the following blog: [Microsoft Security Bulletin MS11-100 – Critical – Issues and Fixes](http://arthicksdev.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/microsoft-security-bulletin-ms11-100-critical-issues-and-fixes/) All I did to fix the problem was I added a configuration setting in web config for appSettings:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5000" />
```

The error thrown on the server as useless.  Crap, why did I become a coder :-)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript included will not help.  I believe you are using an update panel?  It's a server-side error within the async request that's being thrown, bubbling up to the client.  You can listen to the AsyncPostBackError event of the ScriptManager control, attach to it and you'll receive all errors that occur during async postbacks.